Two questions around some new card game based on prime factorization.
I have been developing a card game called "Infinity", which involves a unique play mechanic based on card interactions. In this game, each card displays a set of symbols, and players match cards based on these symbols under specific conditions.
Here is a picture of a game against the computer:

Gameplay Rules:

The game is played with a deck of c unique cards distributed among p players.
Each player begins with n cards and plays clockwise.
A "hit" occurs during a player's turn when the card they play matches exactly one differing symbol compared to the last card on the stack called "pot". If a player has a hit, he collects all the cards in the pot, but his played card stays in the pot. (Additionally to make it more dynamic, the player who has a hit can reverse the direction of the game if he wishes.).
If all players have no cards on their hand, the last player who did a hit collects the remaining cards from the pot.
The player with the most collected cards, wins the game.

Number theoretic interpretation:
Each card has a number $a$ and the symbols correspond bijectively to the prime factorization of $a$: Symbols of $a$
$$S_a = \{ p^k | 1 \le k \le v_p(a), p|a \}$$
Then a hit between $a,b$ occurs iff:
$$\max\{a/b,b/a\} \text{ is a prime number}$$
This leads to an interesting question regarding the probability of a "hit" occurring:
Question:
Given p players and a deck of c cards numbered from $1$ to $c$, what is the minimum number of cards n each player must randomly draw to guarantee that at least one "hit" will occur during the game? ( I will assume that as soon as a player has the possibility to do a hit with the pot, he or she will do so. For otherwise if the players play on intent to avoid hits, then there is the sequence by @PeterTaylor which avoids hits: $2,3,4,5,6,\ldots$ since $m,m+1$ have $\gcd(m,m+1)=1$ and so $\max\{m/(m+1),(m+1)/m\}$ is not a prime number.)
This problem seems to intersect elements of combinatorics and probability theory and number theory. Any insights or related mathematical principles that could help in determining or estimating this minimum n would be greatly appreciated.
This game is based on some hobby research I did two years ago:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/432018/why-is-this-bipartite-graph-a-partial-cube-if-it-is
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/432283/example-of-sequence-of-graphs-which-satisfy-the-riemann-hypothesis-or-the-prime
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433512/largest-eigenvalue-of-a-laplacian-matrix-to-lower-bound-the-prime-counting-funct
Is this a $T_1$ topological space and what other properties (or name) does this topological space on the set of prime powers have?
Alternatively I would also be interested in the following question: Suppose there are two players each with a set of cards $1,2,3,\ldots,c-1,c$ and in the pot is the starting card $1$. For instance we might have $c=33$. Is the game fair or is there a strategy with which the starting / the other player can always win?  ( I am not sure how the wording is in game theory, so excuse my language it does not fit.)
This question has been originally asked at MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/469780/infinity-a-card-game-based-on-prime-factorization-and-a-question but I feel that maybe the second question is more appropriate for this site then for MO.

Sadly I'm pretty weak at number theory, and I've noticed every time an interesting question is posted, there is not even a single comment in it. Wish I could help

@Gwen: Thanks for your kind words.

Do collected cards enter the game again, or are they simply kept as a score? Say I just collected two cards from the pot. Can I play these cards when it is my turn again?

@SomeCallMeTim: Good question, I am experimenting with different set of rules, but in this question, collected cards do not enter the game again but they build the score.

This is not a full answer, but too long for a comment. I doubt you will be able to find a neat formula to your first question. Let $NH(p,c)$ be the maximal $n$ such that we can have a game with $n$ cards for each of the $p$ players with no hit. Then of course, your desired number is $NH(p,c)+1$. By definition, it is clear that $NH(p,c)\leq\lfloor\frac{c}{p}\rfloor$. Also, it holds that $NH(p,c)\leq NH(p,c+1)$ for any $p,c$, since from the $c+1$ cards, you could always select the same two sets of $n$ cards for which there is no hit as in the $c$ case.
I'll say some more about the $p=2$ case, since it is the simplest. Things may generalise.
For $c$ even, we have a stronger than trivial result, $NH(2,c)\leq \frac{c}{2}-1$.
It is clear from your linked posts that you have thought about the graph-theoretic aspect of this, thus, I will be sparing with the details. In the associated graph as in your first link, having the maximal $n$, i.e. $NH(2,c)= \frac{c}{2}$, corresponds to giving a partition of the vertices of the graph into two subets so that no two vertices from the different sets are neighbours (I will argue this in a second). This is impossible, as the graph is connected.
The reason this is equivalent is that the set of such partitions is in bijection with the possible hands of the two players, and if they have a card each that together form a hit, then whenever one plays their corresponding card, the other will have to put down theirs, forming a hit.
Furthermore, you can do lower bounds. A very naïve lower bound is to take one hand a subset of the set of $1$ together with all the primes except $2$, and for the other hand take all primes less than $\frac{c}{4}$ multiplied by $4$. These hands cannot form a hit, and so this will give you a lower bound of $NH(2,c)\gg \pi\left(\frac{c}{4}\right)\sim \frac{c}{4\log c}$. Much more clever lower bounds are possible.
I ran a very naïve program computing $NH(2,c)$ for $2\leq c\leq 24$, and got, respectively, $$0,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10.$$
Thus, $NH(2,c)=\lfloor\frac{c}{2}\rfloor$ for odd $c$ and $NH(2,c)=\frac{c}{2}-1$ for even $c$ are both achieved for certain $c$, so no strictly stronger bound can be found, but we see that the actual function grows slower than $\frac{c}{2}$. How slow I cannot guess for now.

EDIT: I will share my code, but know that it is neither efficient nor clever. In fact it is horrible inefficient. It runs slow in the $20$'s, and I think you will have a memory error in the $30$'s. It is written in Python, with absolutely no regards to best practise. You will find nested for loops everywhere.
Quick explanation: To compute $NH(2,c)$, I start at the upper bound provided above and brutally check for a solution, then iterate my way down until I reach $NH(2,c-1)$, which we know to be a lower bound. To check for a solution at step $n$, I simply find all subsets of $\lbrace 1,\dots,c\rbrace$ of size $n$, then count the numbers in the complement that cannot form a hit with any card from my subset. If the count is at least $n$, I have found a solution, otherwise, try with the next subset.
#Infinity Card game for p = 2

from math import ceil
from itertools import combinations
from sympy import isprime

#Highest choice of c
lim = 25

#This is NH(2,c), for c starting at 0
results = [0,0,0]

#This variable saves NH(2,c-1)
nprev = 0

#Two variables saving a possible maximal pair of hands for which no hit can occur
goodhand = []
enemyhand = []

for c in range(3,lim):
    cards = {i for i in range(1,c+1)}
    #h below is the upper bound on NH(2,c) described above
    h = ceil(c/2)-1
    res = 0
    for i in range(h,nprev,-1): #Iterating backwards over possible size of hand
        poss = list(combinations(cards,i)) #Generating possible hands of size i
        #For each hand, we find cards for which no hit can occur
        for hand in poss: 
            rest = cards.difference(hand)
            good = 0
            goodset = []
            for a in rest: #Iterating over remaining cards
                bad = 0
                for b in hand: 
                    m = max([a/b,b/a])
                    #If there is a possible hit with any card in the hand, discard
                    if m == int(m) and isprime(int(m)):
                        bad = 1
                        break
                if bad:
                    continue
                good += 1 #If loop was not stopped, then a is a possible card for the opponent
                goodset.append(a)
            #If we have found enough cards for the opponent, we have a solution!
            if good >= i: 
                goodhand = hand
                enemyhand = goodset
                res = i
                break
        #If we have found a solution, no need to check for lower size of hand
        if res > 0:
            break  
    #If we did not find a higher solution, take the old one          
    if res == 0: 
        res = nprev
    nprev = res #New minimum set
    print("for c=",c," we have n=",res," with the hands",goodhand," and",enemyhand)

Here is the output:
for c= 3  we have n= 1  with the hands (2,)  and [3]
for c= 4  we have n= 1  with the hands (2,)  and [3]
for c= 5  we have n= 2  with the hands (2, 4)  and [3, 5]
for c= 6  we have n= 2  with the hands (2, 4)  and [3, 5]
for c= 7  we have n= 2  with the hands (2, 4)  and [3, 5]
for c= 8  we have n= 3  with the hands (1, 5, 7)  and [4, 6, 8]
for c= 9  we have n= 3  with the hands (1, 5, 7)  and [4, 6, 8]
for c= 10  we have n= 4  with the hands (1, 5, 7, 10)  and [4, 6, 8, 9]
for c= 11  we have n= 4  with the hands (1, 5, 7, 10)  and [4, 6, 8, 9]
for c= 12  we have n= 5  with the hands (1, 5, 7, 10, 11)  and [4, 6, 8, 9, 12]
for c= 13  we have n= 5  with the hands (1, 5, 7, 10, 11)  and [4, 6, 8, 9, 12]
for c= 14  we have n= 6  with the hands (3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12)  and [5, 7, 10, 11, 13, 14]
for c= 15  we have n= 6  with the hands (3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12)  and [5, 7, 10, 11, 13, 14]
for c= 16  we have n= 6  with the hands (3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12)  and [5, 7, 10, 11, 13, 14]
for c= 17  we have n= 7  with the hands (1, 5, 10, 11, 13, 15, 17)  and [4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 14, 16]
for c= 18  we have n= 7  with the hands (1, 5, 10, 11, 13, 15, 17)  and [4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 14, 16]
for c= 19  we have n= 8  with the hands (1, 5, 10, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19)  and [4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 14, 16, 18]
for c= 20  we have n= 8  with the hands (1, 5, 10, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19)  and [4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 14, 16, 18]
for c= 21  we have n= 9  with the hands (1, 7, 11, 13, 14, 15, 17, 19, 21)  and [4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 16, 18, 20]
for c= 22  we have n= 9  with the hands (1, 7, 11, 13, 14, 15, 17, 19, 21)  and [4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 16, 18, 20]
for c= 23  we have n= 10  with the hands (1, 7, 11, 13, 14, 17, 19, 21, 22, 23)  and [4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 16, 18, 20]
for c= 24  we have n= 10  with the hands (1, 7, 11, 13, 14, 17, 19, 21, 22, 23)  and [4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 16, 18, 20]


EDIT 2:
A few more data points. It is interesting that it has continued to build on basically the same hand for quite a few steps now.
for c= 25  we have n= 11  with the hands (1, 7, 11, 13, 14, 15, 17, 19, 21, 22, 23)  and {4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 16, 18, 20, 24, 25}
for c= 26  we have n= 11  with the hands (1, 7, 11, 13, 14, 15, 17, 19, 21, 22, 23)  and {4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 16, 18, 20, 24, 25}
for c= 27  we have n= 12  with the hands (1, 7, 11, 13, 14, 15, 17, 19, 21, 22, 23, 26)  and {4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 16, 18, 20, 24, 25, 27}
for c= 28  we have n= 12  with the hands (1, 7, 11, 13, 14, 15, 17, 19, 21, 22, 23, 26)  and {4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 16, 18, 20, 24, 25, 27}
for c= 29  we have n= 12  with the hands (1, 7, 11, 13, 14, 15, 17, 19, 21, 22, 23, 26)  and {4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 16, 18, 20, 24, 25, 27}
for c= 30  we have n= 13  with the hands (1, 7, 11, 13, 14, 17, 19, 21, 22, 23, 25, 26, 29)  and {4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 16, 18, 20, 24, 27, 30}

I realised we have another functional bound, namely
$$NH(p,c)\leq NH(p,c-1)+1$$
since if we have a set of hands of $n$ cards each for #cards$=c$, then only at most one hand contain the card $c$, so removing this and removing a random card from each other hand will give you a set of hands of $n-1$ cards for $c-1$.
This allows a small optimization of the code above, and I hoped it would allow for other methods to generate solutions "ground-up", but I failed at implementing it effectively.

Thanks, great answer. Would you mind to share your program?

@mathoverflowUser I edited the answer with my code.

@mathoverflowUser I made another edit. I don't see an immediate way to make significant progress, so I'll stop for now, but I'll keep an eye on the thread :)

Thanks for your help so far! :-)

Linear lower bound for two players
Following on from SomeCallMeTim's excellent answer, I have a lower bound that is a ~constant fraction of the deck, though not much more clever.
Basic version
The simplest version is to deal cards like this:

Player A gets cards that are multiples of 2 but not multiples of 3. For $c$ divisible by 6, this is $\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{2}{3} = \frac{1}{3}$ of the deck.
Player B gets cards that are multiples of 3 but not multiples of 2. For $c$ divisible by 6, this is $\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{6}$ of the deck.

For example, for $c = 30$:

Player A would get $2, 4, 8, 10, 14, 16, 20, 22, 26, 28$.
Player B would get $3, 9, 15, 21, 27$.

For larger decks this pattern repeats modulo 6.
Neither player can ever hit, since any play would have to both lose a factor of 2 and gain a factor 3 or vice versa. Therefore, we can deal up to $\frac{1}{6}$ of the deck to each player while still having the possibility of a no-hit game.
Enhanced version
This can be enhanced somewhat by giving extra factors to player B:

Player A gets cards that are multiples of 2 but not multiples of 3 nor 5.
For $c$ divisible by 30, this is $\frac{1}{2} \cdot \left(\frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{4}{5}\right) = \frac{8}{30}$ of the deck.
Player B gets cards that are multiples of 3 and/or 5 but not multiples of 2. For $c$ divisible by 30, this is $\frac{1}{2} \cdot \left(1 - \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{4}{5}\right) = \frac{7}{30}$ of the deck.

For example, for $c = 30$:

Player A would get $2, 4, 8, 14, 16, 22, 26, 28$.
Player B would get $3, 5, 9, 15, 21, 25, 27$.

For larger decks this pattern repeats modulo 30.
By optimizing the $\frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{4}{5}$ term using other prime denominators, we could get even closer to dealing $\frac{1}{4}$ of the deck to each player, though I'm not certain whether or not we can get arbitrarily close.

I do not understand your notation.

I added example deals. Hopefully this makes more sense.

Nice, this is a great lower bound. This implies in particular that $NH(2,c)\sim \frac{c}{d}$ for some $2<d\leq 4$, in essence. I'm trying to rewrite the code to be a lot more efficient and thus get more data, and hopefully I can approximate $d$.

To be precise, it does follow that we can get arbitrarily close to $\frac{c}{4}$ when $c\to\infty$. Picking the primes $p_1,\dots,p_k$, define $P = \prod \frac{p-1}{p}$. Then the formulas are $\frac{1}{2}P$ for A and $\frac{1}{2}(1-P)$ for B. It is clear that they sum to $\frac{1}{2}$. Since there are infinitely many primes, there are arbitrarily large primes, so for any $P$ with $P>\frac{1}{2}$, we may always find a $p_{k+1}$ such that $P>P\cdot\frac{p_{k+1}-1}{p_{k+1}}>\frac{1}{2}$. Repeating this progress, we can get arbitrarily close to $\frac{1}{4}$ for both players (when $c$ large).

@HighDiceRoller:Thanks for your answer.
